# Acquiring multiple attributes from .xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an .xml file with the structure below. I am wanting to acquire the attribute value, 0.05 and so on, for specific EndPointChannelID's. I am currently able to get the value but it is for every EndPointChannelID instead of for a desired one. Another twist is that the readings are not always going to be 6. How can I achieve only storing the values from the desired EndPointChannelID? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

```
    <Channel ReadingsInPulse="false">
       <ChannelID EndPointChannelID="5154131" /> 
         <ContiguousIntervalSets>
            <ContiguousIntervalSet NumberOfReadings="6">
               <TimePeriod EndRead="11386.22" EndTime="2013-01-15T02:00:00Z"/> 
                  <Readings>
                     <Reading Value="0.05" /> 
                     <Reading Value="0.04" /> 
                     <Reading Value="0.05" /> 
                     <Reading Value="0.06" /> 
                     <Reading Value="0.03" /> 
                     <Reading Value="0.53" /> 
                  </Readings>
               </ContiguousIntervalSet>
           </ContiguousIntervalSets>
       </Channel>
```

Below is the current code I have to find the Value.

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FileLocation);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Reading"))
             {
                 if (reader.HasAttributes)
                 {
                      MessageBox.Show(reader.GetAttribute("Value"));
                 }
              }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with `XMLReader` path, you can do it by setting up a result list, wait for the desired channel ID, start collecting the values, and then end collecting them when the desired channel ID tag ends:

```
var values = new List<string>();
var collectValues = false;
var desiredChannelId = "5154131";
while (reader.Read())
{
     if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
     {
         if (reader.Name == "ChannelID" && reader.HasAttributes) {
             collectValues = reader.GetAttribute("EndPointChannelID") == desiredChannelId;
         }
         else if (collectValues && reader.Name == "Reading" && reader.HasAttributes)
         {
              values.Add(reader.GetAttribute("Value"));
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit too simple. You need to read line by line and first match on EndPointChannelId. Set a flag to make it clear that you have the correct ChannelId, then, when that condition is met read the `Value` attributes. You'll need an array to save them into. An `ArrayList` would be ideal since it is of variable length.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using LINQ to XML:

```
// load document into memory
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

// query the document and get List<decimal> as result
List<decimal> values = (from ch in xDoc.Root.Elements("Channel")
                        where (int)ch.Element("ChannelID").Attribute("EndPointChannelID") == 5154131
                        from r in ch.Descendants("Reading")
                        select (decimal)r.Attribute("Value")).ToList();
```