# XML Multiple attributes

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I got something like this:

```
<item name="Whatever">
    <Point x="12312" y="24234" />
    <Point x="242342" y="2142" />
</item>
```

I need to parse this item in an array if the array contains a name and a list of points.

I didn't really use xml before.

this is my code behind so far

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Gestures.xml");
while (reader.Read())
{
    KnownGestures temp = new KnownGestures();
    IList<Point> GesturePath = new List<Point>();
    // Only detect start elements.
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        // Get element name and switch on it.
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "Gesture":
                // Detect this element.
                temp.GestureName = reader["Name"];
                break;
            case "Point":
                var XValue = reader["X"];
                var YValue = reader["Y"];
                Point tempPoint = new Point {X = double.Parse(XValue), Y = double.Parse(YValue)};
                GesturePath.Add(tempPoint);
                temp.GesturePath = GesturePath;
                break;
        }

        GesturesList.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Edited

Comment: Shouldn't this be a good time to start using it? What have you done so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acquiring multiple attributes from .xml file in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908191/acquiring-multiple-attributes-from-xml-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I've edited the post , maybe the code behind will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) easier to use

```
var points = XDocument.Load(filename)
            .Descendants("Point")
            .Select(p => new Point((int)p.Attribute("x"), (int)p.Attribute("y")))
            .ToList();
```